# Use form to create Android APK server side

Tags: php, android, html, apk

I would like to create a form to be hosted on my server where I can input a URL and an android APK will be generated that displays the URL using WebView.  Can this process be completed end to end on the server?  If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Nice thought! I would like to go about doing this in the following way.

Preliminary, you need an Android dummy application which have a WebView opening an url. This application needs to read the url from strings.xml (or Any other config xml).

You can then build this application using ANT commands, which can compile, build and export this application.

Then I will write the server application which do this

1. Take the url and place it in the Strings.xml or conf.xml
2. Build the app using ANT command
3. Provide the location of generated APK to the server to render the download link to the user.

Hope this helps